# Infinite Matrices from $l^p$ to $l^{\frac{p}{p-1}}$ that are compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces, compact-operators

I wanted to ask if my proof (sketch) of the following statement is correct. Namely, let $p>1$ and define $q= \frac{p}{p-1}$ we are given an operator $K : l^{p} \rightarrow l^{q}$ defined as $x \rightarrow \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_{jk}x_k$ where $\sum_{j,k \in \mathbb{N}} a_{jk}^{q} < \infty$. In order to show that this map is compact, I wanted to proceed along the following steps

- Use reflexivity of $l^p$ to use $K$ compact iff $K$ maps weakly converging sequences to strongly converging ones.
- We find that the map $l_j (x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_{jk}x_k$ is in $(l_p)^*$ since it is bounded
- Then for any weakly converging sequence, $x^k \rightarrow x$, we now we use that
  $$\Vert K(x^m - x) \Vert = \left(\sum_{j\in \mathbb{N}} \left| l_j(x^m -x)\right|^{q}\right)^{1/q}$$
  and can for every $\epsilon > 0$ find m (if necessary passing to a diagonal sequence) s.t for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$, $| l_j(x^m -x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2^j}$ by weak convergence of $x^m$.
- Now reinserting this estimate into the norm and get that our sequence converges in the norm.

Is this proof correct? (maybe when producing the estimate I wonder whether $| l_j(x^m -x)| < \epsilon a_{jm}$ actually suffices which is definitely given?

Best Regards

Comment: How do you know that the $m$ that works doesn't go to $\infty$ as $j\to \infty$?